# How to set up a release date with Managed Publishing in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I found and turned on Managed Publishing in the Google Play console and my app has already been approved, so I have the option to "Review and Publish" it, but that does it immediately. There's a lot of talk around that managed publishing is suppose to replace the old Timed Publishing, but I haven't been able to find any explicit tutorial to **how and where exactly to set up a date to publish the app automatically in the new managed publishing?** Is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?